# Escaping plus signs doesn't work

Tags: regex, sed

I'd like to delete all lines with 3 plus signs:

```
+++ 3 plus signs
+ 1 plus sign
+++ 3 plus signs
```

Here's my sed command, escaping the plus signs after beginning of line

```
sed '/^\+\+\+/d'    -> This erase all lines
sed '/^+++/d'       -> This works and show only the 1 plus sign line
```

Why? Is there any problem while escaping the plus sign?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*"A quick comment. The original sed did not support the "+" metacharacter. GNU sed does if you use the "-r" command line option, which enables extended regular expressions."*

([Source](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html))

If you don't use `sed -r`, then you don't have to escape `+` since it is not considered a metacharacter.

Comment: @Tom It is worth noting that regular expressions have 3 popular syntax forms: basic, extended, and perl-compatible. Regular sed (without -r) implements basic form.